# Unnormalized UTF-8 directory names

Tags: filesystems, unicode, character-encoding

I noticed something interesting in one of my directories:

```
$ ls -li
total 36
2625309 drwxrwxr-x 2 dotancohen dotancohen 4096 Jul  4  2022  Español
2625385 drwxrwxr-x 2 dotancohen dotancohen 4096 Jul  4  2022  Español
2625396 drwxrwxr-x 2 dotancohen dotancohen 4096 Jul  4  2022  Français
2625406 drwxrwxr-x 2 dotancohen dotancohen 4096 Jul  4  2022  Français

$ ls Espa<tab><tab>
Español/ Español/

$ echo Espa* | od -tx1 -c
0000000  45  73  70  61  6e  cc  83  6f  6c  20  45  73  70  61  c3  b1
          E   s   p   a   n 314 203   o   l       E   s   p   a 303 261
0000020  6f  6c  0a
          o   l  \n
0000023
```

Note that these are different directories - they have different inode numbers (the first column, that's why the `-i` flag was used). The two Spanish directories have different names, one has a name consisting of **seven** characters: `E` `s` `p` `a` `ñ` `o` `l`. The other has a name consisting of **eight** characters: `E` `s` `p` `a` `n` `COMBINING TILDE` `o` `l`. Visually, the two filenames are indistinguishable and it is plausible that any software would create one or the other. The [`COMBINING TILDE`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0303/index.htm) is printed in the same "space" as the `n` character preceding it.

These are actually notes that I made on an Android device (Samsung Note 3) several years ago, then copied via ADB to my Linux desktop and let sit there until recently. This opens a world of questions:

1. Who is responsible for normalizing combining characters? I'm thinking that delegating this responsibility to the program writing the file (or, shudder, to the end user) will just exacerbate this problem. Should we propose filesystem normalizations?
2. Do there exist any tools for dealing with normalization issues in filesystems? Such as finding directories with the same names in different normalization forms, and for possibly deduping and merging such directories? Maybe also for bringing the whole filesystem into a standard normalization form without updating e.g. mtimes.
3. What programs might break on these issues? `ncdu` and `find` seem to not have issues, but I'd love to know if some other software might not handle directories with the same name in different normalizations very well. Such as overwritting the content of one directory when the user meant to write to the other because the software normalized the filename written differently than the filename opened.
4. What else did I not think of?

Comment: Are there two directories with names that look the same but may differ in invisible characters or character ecncoding? Does a hexdump show differences? Example: `echo Espa* | od -tx1 -c`. I don't think that programs will consider the two names the same, my guess is that they only look the same when displayed in the terminal.

Comment: or `ls -b` to show escapes for nongraphic characters

Comment: @Bodo Yes, these are different directories - this can be seen that they have different inode numbers (the first column, that's why the `-i` flag was used). The two Spanish directories have different names, one has a name consisting of **seven** characters: `E` `s` `p` `a` `ñ` `o` `l`. The other has a name consisting of **eight** characters: `E` `s` `p` `a` `n` `COMBINING TILDE` `o` `l`. Visually, the two filenames are indistinguishable and it is plausible that any software would create one or the other.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you, the `-b` flag changed nothing in the `ls` output. I've added the output of `od` to the question.

Comment: Which normalization scheme should be used, NFD or NFC? Since UNIX/Linux file systems have always allowed any characters in file names other than `/` and `\0`, normalization would be a change in file system behavior. It would incur some overhead in checking file names and may break programs that use the other scheme then the one chosen for the file system.

Comment: The directory names were most probably created by the notes software based on something you typed. The different encoding might be related to the virtual keyboard software. (updated version, different app, changed language ...)

Comment: I have no real opinion on NFD vs NFC. It seems to me far more logical to normalize in NFC because it really represents the characters used, however I understand that NFD has advantages (sorting, searching). I'd be happy with **either**. But not **both**.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a universal solution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Errors_due_to_normalization_differences

Comment: Lots of problems don't have universal solutions ))